# Mechanic Didn't Diagnose Full Problem

Tags: ac

I recently went in to get my AC looked at.

They tested it, said that all it needed was a compressor.

I was quoted $826 and change to have my air conditioner fixed.

I saved up that sum, came in to have it fixed, and then it was discovered, after I took delivery of the vehicle, that the AC was still not working.

I took the vehicle back immediately and further diagnostics were performed.

It was at that point that the "large" leak in the evaporator was discovered.

The estimate for the additional evaporator is $700.

This is not possible for quite some time.

I am out $826, with warm AC.

My issue is that the extent of the problem wasn't fully addressed or fully diagnosed, and instead of planning for $826 I should've planned for $1,756, which would've made things different.

The compressor was in fact broken, as well as the evaporator, so they all need to be replaced. I'm just not pleased with how the current situation is.

What would one do in this situation? Suck it up and save the rest? Bring it up to the owner?

Thanks.

Comment: If they charged you for the labor to diagnose the problem, you might ask for that to be refunded, or credited toward the repair. But shops often do that anyway: if you have the repair done at their shop, there's no charge for the diagnosis. In that case I'm not sure what you can reasonably ask for.

Comment: As unfortunate as this story is, I don't see this as something that can be answered objectively. Voting to close as a primarily opinion-based question